# stationary controll error in syntax for python as Series

Tags: python, function, syntax, syntax-error, series

```
def stationary(Series) 
    result = adfuller(Series)
        if(result[1]<0.05):
            return 'stationary'
        else:
            return 'not stationary'
```

hi everyone, what do i have to modify?
this is only for the stationary control...thank you.

Comment: 1. Your `def` statement lacks a trailing colon: `def stationary(Series):`. 2. Your `if` block is indented from the previous line and should not be.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thank you for the contribution and your answer...i miss just the :